# How to solve $y''(x)+\frac{1}{x}y'(x) = 0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm solving a differential equation by using reduction of order, which results in solving:

> $$y''(x)+\frac{1}{x}y'(x) = 0$$

I have found $y(x) = \ln x + C$ to be valid solution, by guessing...

Is there a way to derive this result in a more formal way?

Comment: This can be seen as a first order differential equation. Solve it as you prefer.

Comment: Let $z(x) = y'(x)$, then you get a first order equation which you can solve by integrating factors.

Comment: Okay, silly me! I guess that's why it's called reduction of order ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting into Sturmian form: $$\frac{1}{x}(xy')'=0$$ Hence $$xy'=c$$ and $$y=\log(x)+c$$ Alternatively (and equivalently), just multiply through by $x$ to yield $$xy''+y'=0$$ Integrate to find that $$xy'=c$$ and the rest is the same.

Comment: Wow, that's a pretty cool way to solve it!

Comment: =) The coolest part about Sturmian form is that it tells you what the weighting function, $r(x)$, in $L^2(a,b,r(x))$ should be to make and operator Hermitian. See theorem 4.15 in Holland's Applied Analysis by the Hilbert Space Method.

Answer (score 2):

Let $z(x)=y'(x)$

$z'+\frac{1}{x}z=0$

$\frac{z'}{z}=-\frac{1}{x}$

$\ln(z)=-\ln(x)+c$

$ln(zx)=c$

$zx=k$

$z=\frac{k}{x}$

$y'=\frac{k}{x}$

$y=k\ln(x)+c$

Done.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply by $x^2$ to get the Euler-Cauchy equation. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation

your equation will become

$$x^2y''+xy'=0$$

let $y=x^m$
$$y'=mx^{m-1}$$

$$y''=m(m-1)x^{m-2}$$

$$m(m-1)+m=0$$
$$m(m-1+1)=0$$
$$m_1=0$$
$$m_2=0$$
hence 
$$y=C_1x^{0x}\ln x+C_2x^{0x}$$
$$y=C_1\ln x+C_2$$